# How to close PrimeFaces socket connection

Tags: sockets, primefaces, websocket, atmosphere

We’re using PrimeFaces 4.0 (socket) and  atmosphere 2.0.3 for server side push in our J2E application.

The issue with application it doesn’t close socket after closing browser or logout from the application. Hence application produce a socket in CLOSE_WAIT status and ultimately it create too many open connections(1024) and it throw below error. Most of the connections on this port on CLOSE_WAIT status.

**JBWEB003008: Maximum number of threads (1024) created for connector with address /0.0.0.0 and port XXX.**

code snippet for socket in JSP

```
<p:socket id="s" channel="#{xxx.eventChannel}"
                onMessage="modelEventHandler.handleModelEvent" widgetVar="xxxSocket" transport="sse"  onClose=""/>
```

I’ve tried to close this by calling java script function on click of logout button but it doesn’t work.

```
function logOut() {
                PF(xxxSocket).disconnect();
            }
```

Comment: I assume in the **real code** you have single quotes around xxxSocket ('xxxSocket')? And  "doesn't work" is to vague

Comment: @Kukeltje - Yes, single quotes is around xxxSocket.And it still not closing socket. The CLOSE_WAIT connection request are still there.

Comment: 'Not closing' != going to "CLOSE_WAIT"... The fact that it **IS** in CLOSE_WAIT on your server means the client send a signal that it does not need/want/uses the socket anymore. https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+CLOSE_WAIT

Comment: My understanding  is CLOSE_WAIT means the operating system knows that the remote application has closed the connection and waits for the local application to also do so.
Here local application is My J2ee application and remote application is Browser. . Please correct me If I’m wrong

Comment: The remote application being the browser, so the browser has done its work, hence using any javascript to try to close it has no meaning since it is already closed from the client... So checking the server side is more important and since PrimeFaces uses atmosphere (of which **you** are using a **very old one**), check that:  https://www.google.com/search?q=atmosphere+CLOSE_WAIT

Comment: I'm looking into amtospehere side. thanks for lead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try PF('chat-socket').disconnect();

Comment: What is 'chat-socket' here ?

Comment: The value of the widgetVar, so effectively, the poster tells you to do what do already do (with the exception that there are 'single' quotes here, but if you do not have that in your page, you'd get an error, so most likely that is a typo in your code

Comment: @Kukeltje Issue has been resolved after disconnecting socket with the help of suggested code changes at server side in logout and session timeout methods.Like RequestContext.getCurrentInstance.execute("  PF('value of widgetVar').disconnect()").

Comment: @Kukeltje Suggested code changes working perfectly for client where server is hosted and its closing all connection after logout or timeout.But when we access application from other location it  establishes more number of socket connections than usual (client from same country where server hosted) all these extra connections hangs in CLOSE_WAIT status. I know there is no any relation between socket and locations. Dont know know why application behaving weirdly for different location.