# Issue with socket connections

Tags: sockets, primefaces, push

My web application is using sockets for server side push. Socket opening and closing handle properly in code.

The issue is application establishes more number of socket connections than usual whenever it access from different locations (country) except where application server is hosted. Eventually all these extra connections hangs in 
CLOSE_WAIT status.

Issue does not accrued when it access from same country where server is hosted. All socket connections getting close successfully.

Application OS - Linux
Technology - Java-j2ee and Primefacess.

Is this can be network issue any idea?

Comment: So you don't have a problem running on windows? Tags are not for what you use but where the problem is.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628306/how-to-close-primefaces-socket-connection And are you SURE clients in the same country do not cause a problem? Sockets do not know anything about geographical locations

Comment: Wait... the duplicate was your own question.... Thanks for referring to that... Might it be that these clients open more new connections for unknown reasons where you do not close the old ones... As 'answered' here, **you** should be closing them

Comment: @Kukeltje As you suggested in my old question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628306/how-to-close-primefaces-socket-connection] ,I've done code changes and its works perfectly for client where server is hosted and its closing all connection after logout or timeout. I know there is no any relation between socket and locations. But dont know know why application behaving weirdly for different location. I can replicate this issue with my local machine where OS is windows.

Comment: Staet by removing the 'accepted' on the other answer and create your own where you create a full example of what works (and fpr which you now say ' in few cases'). The accepted answer is plain wrong. Lets start from there then

Comment: @Kukeltje I had accepted because i thought issue resolved but late evening I tested it for different location and it failed. Anyhow I will continue it on old thread.

Answer (score 0):

CLOSE_WAIT means that *you* aren't closing the connection. Network conditions have nothing to do with it.